# the probability that there will be exactly two men between A and B?

Tags: combinatorics

If six men, among whom are A and B, stand in a circle, what is the probability that there will be exactly two men between A and B?

Comment: What did you try? What makes this problem difficult for you?

Comment: I found there are 3 ways I can arrange AB in a circle in such a  way that rotating the circle doesn't make difference. and since AB can be interchange so there should be 2*3 ways of getting them in a circle with given condition. I think the total number of ways should be 6 *5 ways. This makes p of 1/5. I don't think I am using the right method here.

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt in the statement of the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: I am a little unsure what you meant by "rotating the circle doesn't make a difference", but $2\times3$ is a legitimate way of counting the number of ways to satisfy the condition, $6\times5$ is the total number of ways to arrange A and B (counted in the same way), and $1/5$ is the correct answer, so really all we needed to do was help you check your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix $A. B$ now has $5$ possible spots of which only $1$ fulfills the criterion,

hence $Pr = \dfrac15$

[Since we are asked the **Pr**, we needn't count arrangements, and can forget about the other $4$ !]

Comment: This one is smart : )

Comment: @cr001: Thank you for your kind comment.

Answer (score 4):

Fix the position of $A$, there are $5!$ arrangement of the other five people, among which $B$ must be fixed at the opposite position so the probability is ${4!\over 5!}$